# How to catch a scroll event in a CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, scroll, clistctrl

I subclassed CListCtrl into my own class, and I use it in several dialogs and views. What I want to do is execute some code when the ClistCtrl is being scrolled vertically. I need this to be in the CListCtrl subclass itself.

I can detect the scrolling triggered when interacting with the scrollbar with the method provided by demoncodemonkey:

messagemap:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyListCtrl, CListCtrl)
    ON_WM_VSCROLL()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

method declaration:

```
class CMyListCtrl : public CListCtrl
{
    //...
protected:
    afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

method implementation:

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    //do some stuff here
    CListCtrl::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

But:

- Mousewheel scrolling does not trigger
  OnVScroll.
- The automatic scrolling happening
  when a CListCtrl item partially
  visible at the bottom is clicked (it
  is scrolled up so the item is
  entirely visible) did not trigger
  OnVScroll either. For example:

[image: partialy visible item]

Clicking on item 9 causes the ClistCtrl to scroll a little so the item is completely visible.

Answer (score 5):

messagemap:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyListCtrl, CListCtrl)
    ON_WM_VSCROLL()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

method declaration:

```
class CMyListCtrl : public CListCtrl
{
    //...
protected:
    afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

method implementation:

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    //do some stuff here
    CListCtrl::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

Comment: This was great to detect the scrollbar scrolling, mousewheel was ignored, and the automatic scrolling happening when a CListCtrl item  partially visible at the bottom is clicked (it is scrolled up so it is entirely visible) was ignored too. I'm editing my original question to include this partial answer. thanks!

Comment: I do agree with you that the WM_VSCROLL doesn't get called in those circumstances, however if what I wrote answered your original question then you should have accepted my answer and then asked a different one.

Answer (score 3):

Mousewheel scrolling trigger OnMouseWheel.

Comment: OnMouseWheel is triggered in the parent dialog. ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT can deal with this if I'm not mistaken, but I don't have a complete example.

Comment: OnMouseWheel IS triggered in the derived class.I've successfully added a ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL to my message map and implemented 'BOOL OnMouseWheel(UINT fFlags, short zDelta, CPoint point)'.

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution is to use `LVN_BEGINSCROLL` or `LVN_ENDSCROLL` notifications that are sent to the parent window. (They also account for mouse-wheel scrolling.)

Although that still doesn't solve the scrolling that occurs when a user moves the focused list item up and down using keyboard.